# On opening my terminal I get Virtualenvwrapper.sh file not found

Tags: virtualenv, bash

I am using Mac and I installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper a long time ago using pip. I was using vitualenv alone most of the times. Recently I was trying to edit my .bash_profile and after that whenever I open my terminal I get the following error

"-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory"

My .bash_profile

```
 1 #export PS1="\u@\h\w: "
  2 # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
  3 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
  4 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
  5 export PATH
  6 
  7 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  8 
  9 # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
 10 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
 11 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
 12 PATH="/usr/local/bin":$PATH
 13 export PATH
 14 
 15 export CLICOLOR=1
 16 export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
 17 
 18 #source "/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
 19 #export WORKON_HOME="/opt/virtual_env/"
 20 
 21 #Randomly taken from stackoverflow post
 22 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
 23 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
 24 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
 25 
 26 # h is the host name, w the complete path
 27 export PS1="\w$ "
```

my .bashrc looks like this

```
  1 #export PS1="\u@\h\w: "
  2 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
  3 
  4 ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
  5 export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
  6 
  7 export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
  8 export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
  9 ##source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
 10 source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
 11 
 12 # h is the host name, w the complete path
 13 #export PS1="\w$ "
```

Can any one tell me where I am going wrong?
What is the difference between .bashrc an .bash_profile?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean, aside from the fact that you ask for `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in one, and that seems to not exist, while you ask for `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in the other?

Comment: I dont know which is the path that I should mention for virtualenvwrapper is it /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh or /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh. Also where should I mention the path in .bash_profile or .bashrc?